# Changing Label Text line depending on Length in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, label

So I am developing an application in `WinForms` and I am populating data from an Access database into a `Combobox`. After populating it I will use the items from the `Combobox` to display data on my labels. This is what I have to populate data:

```
public void AutoCompleteBrand()
{
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(cs.DBConn);
    con.Open();

    adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    adapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT DISTINCT RTRIM(Phone) FROM tblPhone", con);

    ds = new DataSet("ds");
    adapter.Fill(ds);
    dtable = ds.Tables[0];
    cmbPhone.Items.Clear();

    foreach (DataRow drow in dtable.Rows)
    {
        cmbPhone.Items.Add(drow[0].ToString());
    }
}
```

Then inside of `Combobox` selected index event I will use this code:

```
private void cmbPhone_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(cs.DBConn);
        con.Open();

        cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT DISTINCT 
                                    Brand, Phone, Tecnology
                                    FROM tblPhone", con);
        OleDbDataAdapter mAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet mDataSet = new DataSet();
        OleDbDataReader mReader;
        mReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (mReader.Read())
        {
            string sBrand = mReader.GetString(0);
            string sPhone = mReader.GetString(1);
            string sTec = mReader.GetString(2);

            lblBrand.Text = sBrand;
            lblPhone.Text = sPhone;
            lblTec.Text = sTec;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
            MessageBox.Show("Erro\nDetalhes: " + ex.Message, "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Basically the technology label is too big and when it reaches a length changes line. It is doable?

Comment: Have you tried setting the AutoSize property of the label?

Comment: Setting it to false and sizing it depending on what I want?

Comment: ah .. then you can use the MeasureString from System.Drawing.Graphics namespace for this purpose. You can get how wide the string would be on the screen and set label width accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. You are working with WPF or Winforms ?

Basicly you can try a few things like :

-If winforms, you can set the autosize property = true of your label.

you can try Something like this :

```
    while (mReader.Read())
    {
        string sBrand = mReader.GetString(0);
        string sPhone = mReader.GetString(1);
        string sTec = mReader.GetString(2);

        lblBrand.Text = sBrand;
        lblPhone.Text = sPhone;
        lblTec.Text = sTec;
        int wdth = sTec.Length * 16; //you can put another value depending your charachter size. 
        lblTech.Size = new Size(wdth, 22);




    }
```

Or if you can give a fix width to your label and you can check the length of your string to add a new line :

```
     int lngth = 100;
     if(sTech.Length > lngth)
     {
       sTech = sTech.SubString(0, lngth) + Environment.NewLine + sTech.SubString(lngth);
     lblTech.Text = sTech;
     }
```

Tell me if it works.

Comment: I've updated the question with it. I will use that method then

Answer (score 0):

you just need to set two properties to your label: `AutoSize` and `MaximumSize`. `AutoSize`tells label to grow (both horizontally and vertically) but `MaximumSize` limits it to certain `Width` and `Height`. So. just do something like this:

```
label1.AutoSize = true;
label1.MaximumSize = new Size(100, 600);
label1.Text = "test string which is pretty long";
```